# How to save camera image when only portrait interface supported

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, ios-camera

I have a a view controller that takes pictures using a `AVCapturePhotoOutput`. 
I have locked the possible orientations of my view controller, so that the camera preview does not rotate:

```
override var supportedInterfaceOrientations : UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
        return .portrait
    }
```

Problem 1: Since I changed that, when I take a picture, the result image has always a `UIImageOrientation == .right`, whether the device was in portrait or landscape mode.

Problem 2: Then I want to save the image to the file system using `UIImageJPEGRepresentation`, but this method does not include the exif information relative to the orientation (which is for now OK, since the orientation is currently wrong because of Problem 1).

I just want to do what many other apps are doing: Showing a camera preview that does not rotate when the device is rotated, but the images taken have the correct orientation, and I can save them.

Is there anyway of doing this without having to rotate the data of the image using drawing methods?

Comment: How are you creating your UIImage?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that when locking the orientation of the interface:

```
override var supportedInterfaceOrientations : UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
        return .portrait
}
```

the preview layer video orientation was not being updated, which is obvious now.
Since the interface orientation is locked, I use the device orientation to tell the connection which orientation to use. That way the buffer data will have the correct orientation

```
@IBAction func shutterButtonDidClick(_ sender: Any) {

        guard let output = self.cameraSession.outputs.compactMap({ $0 as? AVCapturePhotoOutput }).first, let photoOutputConnection = output.connection(with: .video), let delegate = self.videoCaptureDelegate else { return }
        let deviceOrientation = UIDevice.current.orientation
        //Important line
        photoOutputConnection.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation(deviceOrientation: deviceOrientation)
        let photoSettings = AVCapturePhotoSettings()
        photoSettings.isHighResolutionPhotoEnabled = true
        photoSettings.flashMode = output.supportedFlashModes.contains(.auto) ? .auto : .off
        photoSettings.isAutoStillImageStabilizationEnabled =
        output.isStillImageStabilizationSupported
        output.capturePhoto(with: photoSettings, delegate: delegate)
    }

extension AVCaptureVideoOrientation {
    init(deviceOrientation: UIDeviceOrientation) {
        switch deviceOrientation {
        case .portrait: self = .portrait
        case .portraitUpsideDown: self = .portraitUpsideDown
        case .landscapeLeft: self = .landscapeRight
        case .landscapeRight: self = .landscapeLeft
        default: self = .portrait
        }
    }
}
```